# An exception of type 'SQLite.SQLiteException' occurred in SQLite-net.DLL but was not handled in user code

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.windows, xamarin.winphone

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhW8u.png)Please help me resolve this error...
I am developing an application using Xamarin Forms. When i run Android Project, the application runs without problems but when i set Windows 8.1 project as the start project, i am gettin the exception:

An exception of type 'SQLite.SQLiteException' occurred in SQLite-net.DLL but was not handled in user code

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: Thank you for the response Ben , I have Added the screenshot in the question Above...

Comment: What SQLite library are you using? Also, have you looked through [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/databases/) guide? Specifically, it looks like your DB has a different file extensions. I use .db3 as the file extension.

Comment: @OfentseBaboile Is "VistaTest.sqlite" an existing db? Usually when you make a connection it looks something like `var conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=VistaTest.sqlite; Version=3;");` Can you share your library source and version? (nuget, github,etc)

Comment: Thank You for you Response Ben..After i replace my conn with var conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=VistaTest.sqlite; Version=3;");

it Works....Please Advice me on what the problem was..

Comment: I think this shows that my database Path does not exist and i first have to check if it exist first and create it....

Comment: From the error screenshot you posted (which truncates the error message, better to post error messages as inline text in your question to avoid such truncation) it does seem that the path could not be found as it says "Could not open database file" but the message is truncated so we can't see why.